# execute virtual environment with nohup

Tags: linux, server, virtual, environment, nohup

I looking to execute a virtual environment on a server to run my analyses. These analyses take a lot of time (min 3 days). So I want use nohup to run my commande.

```
source activate qiime2-2019.1    
nohup qiime feature-classifier classify-consensus-vsearch \
        --i-query OTU-marion.qza \
        --i-reference-reads CO1-midori-20180221-seqs.qza \
        --i-reference-taxonomy CO1-midori-20180221-taxo.qza \
        --p-perc-identity 0.97 \
        --p-min-consensus 0.85 \
        --o-classification 5-classify-OTU-marion-vsearch.qza &
```

But I can't execute my virtual environment with nohup and when I close the server's prompt my commande abort ...

```
nohup source activate qiime2-2019.1  
                               
nohup: inputs are ignored and output is appended to 'nohup.out'
nohup: cannot execute command 'source': No file or folder of this type
```

Anyone know how I can do this ?
Thanks
Marion

Comment: Have you tried putting the `source activate` command your qiim command inside the same bash script, and try to `nohup` the bash script ?

Comment: @Blusky, Its seem to work thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Blusky seems to work !

> Have you tried putting the source activate command your qiim command inside the same bash script, and try to nohup the bash script